Is there a series expansion of the complex signum function?
I am interested in finding a series expansion of the complex signum function
$$
\text{sgn}(z)=\frac{z}{|z|}=e^{i\text{arg}(z)}
$$
that converges in some region of the complex plane with $\text{Im}[z]\neq 0$. I am aware of series expansions of the real signum function, such as the Chebyshev expansion
$$
\text{sgn}(x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}T_{2n-1}(x),\quad x\in [-1,1]
$$
I did some numerical testing of this expansion with complex inputs and it does not seem to converge even for complex numbers with relatively small (non-zero) imaginary parts. I am also aware that you can write $\text{sgn}(z)$ in terms of $\text{Re}[z]$ and $\text{Im}[z]$ separately, but I am specifically interested in a representation using just polynomials of $z$ directly. I would also be interested in a representation that is the limit of a function with a series expansion.
If such an expansion does not exist, I am wondering why not, given that the real $\text{sgn}(x)$ function is not analytic yet has a converging series for $x\in [-1,1]$.

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}T_{2n-1}(x)$ is not a power series. And $z/|z|$ is nowhere holomorphic.

The function $\operatorname{sgn}z = e^{i\operatorname{arg}z} = \sqrt{z/\bar{z}}$ is not analytic, that is why you cannot consider a polynomial expansion with respect to the variable $z$ alone, but you will need a bivariate expansion in $z$ and $\bar{z}$, because two parameters (such as $\mathrm{Re}(z)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(z)$ with cartesian coordinates) are needed to parametrize the complex plane.

By Osgood's theorem, if $f_n$ are holomorphic, $D$ is open set and $f_n \to f$ pointwise on some dense subest of $D$, then $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ on some open dense subset of $D$ - in particular, $f$ is holomorphic on this subset. As your function is nowhere holomorphic, it can't be pointwise approximated by holomorphic functions on any subset which closure has non-empty interior, in particular in any region.
(I am also not sure if Chebyshev approximation converges pointwise on $[-1, 1]$, general result gives convergence only in $L_2$, but that's separate question)
